# Array's in PHP LIFO or FIFO?

Tags: php

I am new to PHP and wants to know whether array's in PHP are LIFO or FIFO. For e.g.

```
$var1 = array('1','2','3');
```

Comment: what prevents you from testing yourself? It'd take less than writing your question here. Voting to close as not constructive.

Comment: An array isn't a queue or a stack, but a hashmap: both queues and stacks are available within the SPL library

Comment: I think this is a reasonable question given that the small amount time spent on it will help others who will have the same query.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

They are what you make them :)

- [`array_pop()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-pop.php) removes an item off the end of an array (the last item that was added)
- [`array_shift()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php) removes the first item off the array (first one added).

So as you can see they are capable of behaving in both ways.

- Last In First Out
- First In First Out

It all depends on how you implement your code.

Comment: Additionally, array_push puts the data at the end of the array.

Comment: @seb - and `array_unshift()` does the same for the other end of the array.

Answer (score 4):

**Updated:**

Well arrays are neither `LIFO` or `FIFO`. Actually, they are both `IMO`. ie. They can behave in both ways. You can make use of the available functions in php the either way (as required), as mentioned by Lix above.

Comment: This is not 100% correct. Its not that they are neither. A more accurate description would be to say that they are both IMO... They *can* behave in both ways..